# MKAnnotationView doesn't show callout

Tags: cocoa-touch

I'm trying to get an MKMapView to show a pin with a callout bubble. I get the pin to display, but I just cant figure out how to display the callout.

There is my code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id)annotation {
    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) {
        return nil;
    }
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Pin"];
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    [pinView setCanShowCallout:YES];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    [self performSelector:@selector(displayPinCallOutView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
    return pinView;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to get the callout to display as soon as the annotation is added to the map, you have to do it in the `didAddAnnotationViews` delegate method:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    //Get reference to annotation you want to select...
    //You could search through mapView.annotations array
    //or keep ivar reference to it.
    id<MKAnnotation> annToSelect = ...

    [mapView selectAnnotation:annToSelect animated:YES];
}
```

Remove the `performSelector` from the `viewForAnnotation` method.

Comment: It doesn't work :( And I can't select the pin and show the callout

Comment: Is the didAddAnnotationViews method getting called (put an NSLog in there)?  Show how you're setting annToSelect.  Not sure what you mean by "can't select the pin and show the callout".

Comment: It's probably because the annotation's title is blank or nil.