# How to set the PlaceMark position in MKMapView?

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

MKMapView show the pin on the center of the mapView, I want to position the pin location above the center. How do I do that?

**Here is my code**

```
- (void) location
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;  
    MKCoordinateSpan span;  
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.1162;  
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.1160;  

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;  
    location.latitude = 65.494806;  
    location.longitude = -23.577569;  
    region.span=span;  
    region.center=location;  

    PlaceMark *add_Annotation = [[[PlaceMark alloc] initWithCoordinate:location] autorelease];
    [add_Annotation setTitle:@"myTitle"];  
    [add_Annotation setSubTitle:@"myAddress"];  
    [mapView addAnnotation:add_Annotation]; 

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];  
    [mapView regionThatFits:region];  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the pin at those coordinates but center the map lower than the pin so that the pin is a little above the center, offset the `center` of the `region` by a fraction of the latitude span.

Instead of this:

```
region.center=location;
```

do this:

```
region.center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
                    location.latitude - (span.latitudeDelta/5.0), 
                    location.longitude);
```

Increase/decrease the divisor to reduce/increase the offset.

Also, the line `[mapView regionThatFits:region];` is not needed--you can remove it.
First, `setRegion` already does `regionThatFits` itself and second, `regionThatFits` *returns* a value but the code is not handling any return value.

Comment: I got the idea! but I'm getting error with your code. Error message: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CLLocationCoordinate2DMake", referenced from:

Comment: Quick question, how do I show the title once the map get started?

Comment: If you mean show the callout as soon as you add the annotation, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168981/mkannotationview-doesnt-show-callout/8170021#8170021