# map with center offset using setusertrackingmode

Tags: ios5, maps, mapkit

When I display a mapView using setusertrackingmode the userlocation is displayed always in the mapcenter.

```
// set tracking mode
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES];
```

Is there a way to display the userlocation with an offset, so it will be e.g. displayed in the lower quarter of the map?

Comment: Instead of setting userTrackingMode, you'd have to manually update the map's region in the didUpdateUserLocation delegate method.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8171775/467105) gives an idea of one way you could apply an offset to the region.

Comment: Thank you! Using setUserTrackingMode helps to avoid the use of an additional location manager. As far as I understood, two location mangers in one App could result in conflicts. Thats why I prefer using setUserTrackingMode.