# How to display map callout on one of the annotation pin automatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have a view which has couple of location locations listed in a table view. If user clicks on any cell the app needs to display the Mapview with the location clicked with callout. 
Till now i have been able to show all the locations on the map view but don't know how to display the callout on the clicked one.

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried setting the clicked location as the center for the region, and setRegion animated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MKAnnotationView doesn't show callout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168981/mkannotationview-doesnt-show-callout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a way of knowing which row in your table view corresponds to which MKAnnotation. In that case, you can just use

```
- (void)selectAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation animated:(BOOL)animated
```

to programmatically select the annotation you're interested in.